# index out of bound exeception when call one item in arraylist

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I want to get one item in array list but it give me error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
i call this listEvent.get(1).getTotal() where listEvent is my arraylist
how can i retrieve an element from arraylist?

here is my code

```
 private void getData() {
        //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer

        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
        //Incrementing the request counter

        if(requestCount <= **listEvent.get(1).getTotal()**) {
            requestCount++;
        }
    }
```

here is my full code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.anakacara.anakacara.App.AppConfig;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.App.Event;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.Helper.CardAdapter;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.R;
import com.anakacara.anakacara.activity.DetailEvent;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link EventFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link EventFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class EventFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    //Creating a List of event
    private List<Event> listEvent;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private int requestCount = 1;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    public EventFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment EventFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static EventFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        EventFragment fragment = new EventFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
            // code
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
            // code
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event,null);;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) x.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) x.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        /**
         * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
         * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
         */
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                        getData();
                                    }
                                }
        );




        //Initializing our event list
        listEvent = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        //Calling method to get data
        getData();

//        swipeRefreshLayout= (SwipeRefreshLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
//        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
//        {
//            @Override
//            public void onRefresh()
//            {
//                if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
////Calling the method getdata again
//                    getData();
//                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                }
//            }
//        });
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(rVOnScrollListener);
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listEvent, getActivity());

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
        itemAnimator.setAddDuration(1000);
        itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailEvent.class);
                intent.putExtra("event_judul", listEvent.get(position).getJudul()); //you can name the keys whatever you like
                intent.putExtra("event_deskripsi", listEvent.get(position).getDeskripsi()); //note that all these values have to be primitive
```

here is my json code

```
0:  {
"id": 5
"judul": "asdfasdfasdf"
"deskripsi": "asfasdfasdfqwer"
"duit": 123123
"persen": 65
"sisahari": 43
"gambar": "http://192.168.0.13/task_manager/image/not4.jpeg"
"total": 4
}-
1:  {
"id": 4
"judul": "asdfasfasdfas"
"deskripsi": "dafasdfasdfasdfasfdasdf"
"duit": 12341234
"persen": 12
"sisahari": 31
"gambar": "http://192.168.0.13/task_manager/image/not3.jpeg"
"total": 4
}
```

i need access total but because in array 0 and 1 it is same i just need to access one of them
i want to using code like this 
            if(requestCount <= 4) {
                requestCount++;
            }
which is 4 is page limit, but i want to get it from array so it will be dynamic instead of manual like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error describes that you are trying to access a position of arraylist which is empty.
If you want to access position 1 of arraylist, you can keep a check in this way before trying to access the value at that postion which will make sure that your app does not crash :

```
if(listEvent.size() > 1 && requestCount <= listEvent.get(1).getTotal())
```

Comment: but it will make it crash. cannot we check the size before? if im check the size like this if(listEvent.size()>= 1 && requestCount <= listEvent.get(1).getTotal() it will make me load double data in my recycleview

Comment: what i want actually get page limit from json. which is the page limit in getTotal. so each item have page limit, but i just want to use 1 item

Comment: Please check my update, and let me know if its what you need

Comment: actually i just need to access total, but because in array 0 and 1 it is same i just need to access one of them to determine the page limit. so actually the code will be same like this if(requestCount <= 4) {
            requestCount++;
        }

Comment: your solution make my app not crash but it will load double things for array 0 and 1 in my recycleview. but if im using manual int like this  if(requestCount <= 4) it dont load double thing for array 0 and 1

Comment: I understand, but the issue posted in the question states that your arraylist is empty, i.e, may be your json is not parsed correctly which in turn might keeps the arraylist empty.

Comment: yeah i know your solution make it work. but can you help me check what is wrong? with my code

Comment: I believe your json has some issues and it is not parsed in proper format, could you post complete exact json response from the server ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106132/discussion-between-philipus-silaen-and-haresh-chaudhary).

Comment: buddy it is because im using old version of teamviewer can you get to discussion again?

Comment: buddy i need your help if you're not busy can we discuss it in chat?

Comment: buddy i need your help if you're not busy can we discuss it in chat?

Comment: buddy i need your help if you're not busy can we discuss it in chat? @HareshChaudhary

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says that you are trying to access the 2nd element in the List where there exists no elements.
You should check the size of the list before accessing it.
You can check as below:

```
if(listEvent.size()>= 2 && requestCount <= listEvent.get(1).getTotal())    {
        requestCount++;
    }
```

PS:

I assume that by using **.get(1)** you are intended to access the second element.
If you want to access the first element you should use** .get(0)**  instead.